# How to connect two points of two different plots using pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code to plot two plots:

```
x = range(mov_x_1.shape[0])
plt.plot(x,mov_x_1)
plt.plot(x, mov_x_2)
plt.show()
```

getting the following result

[image]

Now I have a variable

```
path = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 9), (8, 9), (9, 9), (10, 10), (11, 11), (12, 12), (13, 13), (14, 14), (15, 15), (16, 16), (17, 17), (18, 18), (19, 19)]
```

that contains tuple of indices. The first element is the index for `mov_x_1` the second for `mov_x_2`.

No I want to connect each index-pair in the graph, so from one point of `mov_x_1` to another point of `mov_x_2`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`LineCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
mov_x_1 = np.random.rand(20) * .1 + .5
mov_x_2 = np.random.rand(20) * .1 + .4
path = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 9), (8, 9), (9, 9), (10, 10), (11, 11), (12, 12), (13, 13), (14, 14), (15, 15), (16, 16), (17, 17), (18, 18), (19, 19)]

x = range(mov_x_1.shape[0])
plt.plot(x,mov_x_1)
plt.plot(x, mov_x_2)

lines = [((i, mov_x_1[i]), (j, mov_x_2[j])) for (i, j) in path]
plt.gca().add_collection(LineCollection(lines, colors='k', linewidths=.5))
```

[image]